# why wordpress inserting images on posts width 1px height 1px. please help me

Tags: wordpress, image, upload

I'm inserting images via 'Add Midia' inside posts.

Automatically it inserts the picture with width="1px" and height="1px"

I noticed that the option for selecting size (thumb, medium, complete size) is not available.

Also, when I try to add a featured image (640x480px), it gets inserted, but nothing is showed above the 'Remove Featured Image Link'

However, in this case if the image is little like 100x67px it is showed.

Please help me 
Thanks

Comment: There really isn't much info to go on here. Is this theme specific? What theme are you using?

Comment: did you fixed this problem? i have the same, and don't know how to solve it

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried: 
 - Try to change the upload folder permissions (777) 
 - Or look here: http://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/screenshots/ 
 - reset the plugins folder by PhpMyAdmin 
 - switch to the default theme 
 - reupload all files

Comment: we try it and make change the permission of upload folder but it not work.

Answer (score 0):

Try these steps:

- Switch to the default theme to rule out any theme-specific problems.
- Cut and paste all plugins to another folder from wp-content/plugins folder (this will disable them all completely). Sometimes, an    apparently inactive plugin can still cause problems.
- Re-upload all files & folders - except the wp-content folder and    wp-config.php & root .htaccess files - from a fresh download of WordPress. Make sure that you delete the old copies of files & folder
  before uploading the new ones.
- Try [Regenerate
  Thumbnails](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/) plugin